# A better word for "synchronised"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, past-participles

I'm struggling to find a better and less "harsh" word for *synchronised*.

I'm trying to convey a message of simplicity for our product which synchronizes viewing of documents on multiple iPads. (The same file opens up simultaneously on multiple iPads, ready to be discussed.)

Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We will be better able to answer your question if you can edit your question to explain the context in which *synchronize* would sound "harsh," what thesaurus or other references you have already checked, and what you find lacking in those suggestions.

Comment: *Simultaneously timed* or *integrated* (in terms of timing) or better still *harmonized* (though it does not suit well to "digital" synchronisation you wish to send a message about). Anyway, you could have looked here http://thesaurus.com/browse/synchronize

Comment: Thanks choster. I've checked with different references and I'm not completely happy with the alternatives. I understand that sometimes there are no alternatives. Synchronised sound technical and I believe people have a natural aversion towards overly technical words. Technical = harsh (to me at least)

Comment: I beg to differ. That the word is technical is actually its strongest suit: it means exactly what you need. So use it. It is *the* ubiquitous, universally accepted, used and understood, precise term. People do not have a natural aversion to clear, concise language. What they do have a natural aversion to is wishy-washy mumbo-jumbo feel-good marketese. If what your product does is synchronize, then say just that and I'll be happy to hear it has that feature. If you start calling it *harmonizing* or *jabberwocking* instead, you will insult my intelligence and lose a potential customer.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I do see Erik's standpoint. The simplest description is not necessarily the most concise description; but which best informs the customers should be Erik's decision. A 'patterned superhydrophobic aerofoil skin' is more technically accurate than a 'ice-repellent airplane wing' but will attract less customers in the headline of a business pamphlet. Indeed if the more technical term attracts you, then you have just fallen for a different form of targeted advertising - they get you coming and going.

Comment: @LateralFractal actually you just made me realize that what I'm really saying is that *synchronized* is not that technical to begin with. Precise and clear, yes. But technical? As I said, it's widely used and understood, universally accepted, ubiquitous. *The* word of choice. Which, I agree with you, cannot be said of "patterned superhydrophobic aerofoil skin". Really not in the same ballpark at all.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect synonym - but how about: *Shared*

Answer (score 1):

You could try *[coordinated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coordinated)*, the past participle of *coordinate*...

> 1. To harmonize in a common action or effort

Comment: +1 And why not *harmonized*?

Comment: @bib, because I'm fast asleep.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[linked](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/linked)* (since they are all linked to the same file)?

> to connect by association, etc.

You could also use the phrase *linked together*, which is a bit redundant, but emphasizes the close connection.

Comment: I like linked, or even linked together. Thank you very much bib

Answer (score 0):

Fluidity.  I was thinking of synchronized swimmers having symmetry and being fluid, but this may not be wholly correct as a lone word and is not past tense.  But if applied to your need of various pages or windows coinciding with each other then fluidity works in my mind.